# A doubt on max distance in a compact subset of a metric space.

Tags: general-topology

**PROBLEM** : A set **A** of a metric space is said to be 'bounded' is it is contained in some ball $B(x,r)$.Let X be a metric space, and let $A\subset  X$, be a compact set.  Show that A must be 'bounded'.

**MY ATTEMPT**:
My attempt itself is incomplete because of my doubt.
Let {$U_i$} denote the open cover of A, and let V = $\cup$ {$U_i$} , where the union is over the i , which form the finite subcover of A.

Consider any $x \epsilon X$. Let $r = max(d(x,y); y\epsilon V)$ [d(x,y) is the distance function].

Now i want to prove that $r$ as defined above indeed exists in X. Because then , it follows that $V \subset B(x,r)$ and since $A \subset V$, it implies $A \subset B(x,r)$, proving that A is bounded.

Can someone suggest how to prove the existence of the max distance, or likewise point out any mistake i made in my deduction.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ was not bounded, $\left\{B(a,n)\right\}_{n=1}^\infty$ with $a \in A$ would be an open cover of $A$ which would not have a finite subcover.

Comment: I understand your proof. However, as an additional help, can you please justify whether a max distance exists as in the attempt above?

Comment: If it would not exist, for all $n$ you would have a point $x \in A$ such that $x \not\in B(a,n)$. As a consequence, $\left\{ B(a,n) \right\}$ would not have a finite subcover and $A$ would not be compact. Thus the max-distance has to exist.